# Calculating for the opposite side, given the hypotenuse and angle

Tags: c, hypotenuse

May I ask what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to calculate for the opposite side, given the angle and hypotenuse. I feel like I'm using sine the wrong way. Need some clarification on why my code isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    
    double fAngle, fHyp;
    
    printf("Angle: ");
    scanf("%lf", &fAngle);

    printf("Hypotenuse: ");
    scanf("%lf", &fHyp);
    
    
    printf("The opposite side is %lf", sin(fAngle) * fHyp);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is your input and output?  Are you entering the angle in radians?

Comment: Unrelated: for some angles you will get a negative length; may want to use `fabs()` or "reduce" the angle.

Comment: I ran your program and entered an angle of 1.04719755133 (π/3) and a hypotenuse of 2.  It gave me 1.732051, which looks about right for √3.

Comment: @pmg Well, they are talking about hypotenuse, so I'd assume a right triangle and (but the program should check)   0 <= `fAngle` < π/2.

Comment: Tip: to improve quality of  `sin()` when `fAngle` is some _large_ value, reduce with `fAngle = fmod(fAngle, 360.0);` before converting to radians.

Comment: Mere Pixel, Tip: post input used, output seen and output expected  to improve the quality of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are entering input in degree angles, while your code expects radian angles.

You can easily convert to radians like this :

```
double fAngle;

printf("Angle: ");
scanf("%lf", &fAngle);
fAngle = fAngle * 2.0 * M_PI / 360.0
```

π radians are equal to 180°

Comment: Ahhh yes. This explains it. Thank you!